# How to put dataframes in a list and then rbind from an R function?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, assign, rbind

This is related to an old question: [R: How do I list a family of datasets and then rbind them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862046/r-how-do-i-list-a-family-of-datasets-and-then-rbind-them)

I'm working on a new function for the OEC package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oec/index.html) so I can batch download data.

Here's my new function that I want to include in my package https://gist.github.com/pachamaltese/3b585dded0a80c031c65e98b268ebcc7

So, this is a MWE

```
#install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("pachamaltese/oec/cran")

library(oec)

getdata_interval("chl","chn",2010,2014,6,2)
```

**How can I assign the dataframes I obtain with this to a list? The problem is not how to do the `rbind`. There's an option of using `rbindlist`, but before doing that I need to be able to put the dataframes in the list before I can move forward. I did this:**

1. Lines 16-17 (in my gist) are working ok

   ```
   envir = as.environment(1)
   assign("getdata_interval_list", replicate(length(years), 0, FALSE), envir = envir)
   ```
2. Then lines 167-168 (in my gist)

   ```
   envir = as.environment(1)
   assign(paste(origin, destination, years[[t]], "4char", sep = "_"), origin_destination_year_6char, envir = envir)
   ```

   do work too.
3. Then I want to add this line

   ```
   assign(getdata_interval_list[[t]], parse(paste(origin, destination, years[[t]], "4char", sep = "_")), envir = envir)
   ```

   and it says `cannot open file 'XXX': No such file or directory` and
   I want to use that line to put `do.call("rbind",
   getdata_interval_list)` in the function and then give the user a
   dataset that has all the information and the pieces of information
   too.

The tricky thing is that I need both the joined datasets and the individual datasets on the globalenv so that users have access to it.

Comment: take a look at `rbindlist` function in `data.table` library:
`data.table::rbindlist`

Comment: Thanks @MahdiJadaliha. I saw that but before I could use it I need to be able to replace the list I made and put the dataframes in the list. That's what  I can't do.

Comment: Take a look at gregor's answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames). My answer there may be helpful in this particular case.

Comment: thanks @lmo, that's an option

Comment: @lmo thanks !! I made some changes to the function and it worked !